# Google Analytics - Capture customer data who clicked a link

Tags: google-analytics

**Javascript**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("...");
            pageTracker._initData();
            pageTracker._trackPageview();
            </script>
```

**HTML**

```
            <a href="http:someurl.com" onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Access','Click','http:someurl.com')">External Link</a></td>
```

Currently, I'm tracking a web link click and it's showing up in the analytics report under

```
Events - Events Category
    with Event category name as 'Access' and Event Action as 'Click'
```

I would like to also capture customer information, (i.e) customers whoever clicked the link.

Will this work?

```
<a href="http:someurl.com" onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Access','Click','http:someurl.com', customerId)">External Link</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you're doing is sending is a value for the event `value` (ie. the fourth parameter). That value should only be an integer (cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#setting-up-event-tracking). What could possibly work better is if you create a custom variable that could potentially be used to store `customerId`, and you could set this at the page scope (cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#pageLevel).

Comment: I added the custom var like below, how that variable gets called in the onclick event of link, Is there any way to call that customvar, <script type="text/javascript">var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='"+gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));   </script><script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker=_gat._getTracker("...");
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1,"CustomerInfo",customerid,3)/*added code*/pageTracker._initData();pageTracker._trackPageview();</script>

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is in the second link I mentioned, under the Using Custom Variables section.

Comment: Yes, I tried that second link. That code is just a declaration, but how that variable gets called during onclick event.

Comment: The variable is already set before the event call and will be applied to all events until the next page load. You can check with GA Debugger to check if your event hit includes that variable.